# How to properly align the xls to bind the table data using a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, stored-procedures

I wrote the stored procedure like this

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[usp_GetTrackAgencyCountReport_Job]
AS
   Declare @BodyMessage Varchar(1000),
        @ToEmail Varchar(254),
        @sql Varchar(max),
        @Count int,
        @intFlag INT,
        @Agent varchar(200),
        @From datetime,
        @To datetime,
        @DbName varchar(100)

        SET @BodyMessage='Please find attached list of Agency names, for how many accounts rated, how many accounts submitted and how many accounts approved to QMS. '
        Select @ToEmail='hemanth@zeninfotech.com;'
        --Select @ToEmail='cpeterson@chris-leef.com; gpeterson@chris-leef.com; info@chris-leef.com'
        SET @To= (SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
        SET @From=(SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -7))
        SET @Agent=''
        SET @DbName='QMSV3Dev'

Begin   
--crete temp table to get the details
CREATE TABLE #tblAgencyCount(AID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,SaveDataCount varchar(50),AgentID varchar(50),GetRateCount varchar(50),ConvertedQuoteCount varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #tblAgencyCount(SaveDataCount,AgentID) select COUNT(*),AQ.AgentID from Agent_Quote AQ where 
        AQ.CreatedOn between @From and @To
        and AQ.AgentID like @Agent +'%' and AQ.StatusCode!='C' group by AQ.AgentID  
SET @intFlag = 1
set @Count=(select COUNT(*) from #tblAgencyCount)
WHILE (@intFlag <=@Count)
BEGIN
declare @Ai int
set @Ai=(select AgentID from #tblAgencyCount where AID=@intFlag)
Update #tblAgencyCount set GetRateCount=(select COUNT(*) from Agent_Quote AQ where 
        AQ.CreatedOn between @From and @To
        and AQ.AgentID like @Ai and AQ.StatusCode!='C' and AQ.LowPrice!='' and AQ.HighPrice!=''),
        ConvertedQuoteCount=(select COUNT(*) from Agent_Quote AQ where 
        AQ.CreatedOn between @From and @To
        and AQ.AgentID like @Ai and AQ.StatusCode!='C' and AQ.ApproveStatus='Approved')
         where AID=@intFlag
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
--end 
    Drop Table Temp_AgencyCount
    Create Table Temp_AgencyCount(AgencyName Varchar(250),SubmittedCount Varchar(50),GetRateCount varchar(50),ApprovedQuoteCount Varchar(50))
    SET @sql='select A.Name,AC.SaveDataCount as SubmittedCount,AC.GetRateCount,AC.ConvertedQuoteCount as ApprovedQuoteCount from #tblAgencyCount AC Left Join ' + @DbName + '..Agent A On AC.AgentID = A.ID order by A.Name'
    Insert into Temp_AgencyCount Values('Agency Name','Submitted Count','GetRate Count','Approved QuoteCount')
    Insert into Temp_AgencyCount Values('------------------------------------','-----------------','---------------','-------------------')
    Insert into Temp_AgencyCount Exec(@sql)
    exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT AgencyName+Space(40-Len(AgencyName))+ ''-   ''+ SubmittedCount+Space(20-Len(SubmittedCount))+''- ''+GetRateCount+Space(20-Len(GetRateCount))+''- ''+ApprovedQuoteCount FROM AgentPortal_Live_21Sept2012..Temp_AgencyCoun
t" queryout C:\WeeklyOnlineSubmissionReport.xls -c -T'
    Select @Count=COUNT(*) from Temp_AgencyCount
    If(@Count!=0)
    Begin
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='Profile',
             @recipients=@ToEmail, @subject='Weekly Online Submission Report', 
             @body=@BodyMessage,@file_attachments='C:\WeeklyOnlineSubmissionReport.xls'
    End
End

--Exec usp_GetTrackAgencyCountReport_Job
```

It is working fine to create the Excel file and send to mail but I don't get correct format in one column in one line like that to display the Excel, how to align, please give me any idea about that

Thank u
hemanth

Answer (score 0):

Hi i t  seems you are missing field delimiter

```
queryout C:\WeeklyOnlineSubmissionReport.xls -c -T'
try like this
queryout C:\WeeklyOnlineSubmissionReport.xls  -c -t,'
```

The -t parameter allows you to specify a field delimiter. The character after -t will be used to separate the data fields. If -t is removed, tab will be used as the default delimiter. 
Pls check  these following sites how to use  it

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1633/simple-way-to-export-sql-server-data-to-text-files/

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-tsql-of-text-files/

check this paragraph   Write data from a TSQL variable into a file